# How to access Shared Memory in Mathematica

Tags: memory

I'm running `Python` code to receive live data stream through web-socket and storing it in the shared memory as the following;

`Python Code`

```
.
.
.
import sysv_ipc, json
queueNumber = 1111
try:
    msq = sysv_ipc.MessageQueue(queueNumber, sysv_ipc.IPC_CREX, )
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    msq = sysv_ipc.MessageQueue(queueNumber)

.
.
.
''' code to receive data from web-socket'''
.
.
.
                a = json.dumps(data)
                msq.send(a.encode())
```

I want to access this data, stored in the shared memory, from `Mathematica`, perform  the computation and put the result back into the shared memory so that, it can be accessed by `Python`.

Can anyone suggest me, how can I access the data in the shared memory from `Mathematica`?

Comment: I'm not aware of a built-in solution. But I recently finished [shared_memory project](https://github.com/ben-izd/shared_memory/) letting people share data between Python - Julia - Matlab - Java - Mathematica using shared memory. You can share a numeric array (signed and unsigned 8, 16, 32, 64 bits + float, double with complex 64, 128) with any dimensions + string between them (with some limitations in Java interface).

Comment: @BenIzd: Can you please provide me the ```.c``` file. My requirement is that I need to share a struct object between ```Python``` and ```Mathematica```.

Comment: The project is built on top of Rust. No `.c` files exist but you can use the native library and header file to call functions in your language of choice. I don't have information about your struct or requirements, but based on your code, just share the JSON dump as a string. You don't have to do anything other than importing the files and calling the functions like [the example shown in the repository](https://github.com/ben-izd/shared_memory#simple-example).

Comment: @BenIzd: Could you please provide ```.so``` file  for linux, instead of the ```.dll``` file?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to Linux to build the `.so` file but the build process for Rust is relatively easy. [Install Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/learn/get-started) and run `cargo build --release` in the `rust` folder. It will download the dependencies and build a `.so` file (assuming you're on Linux).